# How to make sure output of <pre> tags is properly aligned

Tags: html

How should I write text inside a `<pre>` tag (in particular consider the presence of other HTML tags such as `<b>` or `<a>`) so that the final result is properly aligned vertically?
Here is an example of what I'd like to achieve:

```
9            texts          blah
10           texts          blah
11           texts          blah
12           texts          blah
```

I'm currently getting things like this:

```
9            texts          blah
10            texts          blah
11            texts          blah
12            texts          blah
```

Comment: consider using a table if this is the behavior u desire

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I ended up making an invisible `<table>` (i.e., `<td style="border: 0">`).

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Could you programmatically add `&nbsp;` in front of any number less than 10? Or add a 0 in front of all single digits during output? Either of those should help "push" the text to the right, plus align the single digits to the ones column in your list.

Comment: Yeah, that would work, but what if we consider strings of different lengths? Consider something like a 5-digit number (e.g. `129007`) after `12`... Or something longer / shorter than `texts`... That's more difficult to code...